# GUI for the Linux and Windows platforms - Python CRUD app

Tags: python

i'm  looking for a basic CRUD (create-read-update-delete) app
in Python, with some line-by-line display grid to browse through a file's
records and select individual records from there. It probably already
exists but i couldn't find anything yet.
Thanks

Comment: What kind of file? What kind of records? Are you looking for an application or code samples?

Comment: Hi Mike, files could be anything from "structured" text files
to DB tables. Records would contain data like client's names
and addresses and so on. No "complex" information.
I'm looking for an application, or some code samples
for beginners (like me).

Comment: @John: Wow that's vague.  Batch?  Web?  GUI?

Comment: @S.Lott: I'm afraid you're right about my vagueness :-o
Remember the goold old FoxPro 2.6 days? A browse-window-like
grid and the CRUD that came with Fox would be enough.
GUI would be OK, Web would be better.

Comment: @John: "GUI would be OK, web would be better" is impossible to parse.  GUI runs on your desktop.  Web runs on a separate web server.  What are you talking about?  Please try to be specific.

Comment: @ S.Lott: A simple GUI would suffice, but considering the apparent simplicity of the Django CRUD example given by Espen, that one could
be an alternative, although more complex than what i need.

Comment: @John:  Please, please, please.  Pick a platform.  Web is not desktop.  Please don't just throw out random options.  Please try and focus.  "GUI would suffice, ... Django ... could be an alternative."  Still don't make sense no matter how many times you repeat it.  Please focus.

Comment: @S.Lott: a GUI for the Linux and Windows platforms, since Python works on both (and others). Should allow browsing through a file's
records and selecting a single record for further action, while
including options for adding new records and deleting existing ones.

Comment: @John: Now, please update your question to actually say "GUI for the Linux and Windows platforms" in the question (since almost no one reads the comments.)

Comment: @S.Lott: Done, thanks for your recommendation.

Answer (score 1):

Isn't Django all about web-based CRUD applications for Python?

Comment: You're probably right, as far as i know it's a complete framework
for web-based apps. Possibly too big for me in this case.

Comment: Instead of developing web based applications use one and access models via the shell using the django framework?

Comment: @Dean: Sounds like a good idea, but implies learning Django first?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe [Camelot](http://www.python-camelot.com/) is what you need.  It is a RAD framework for creating desktop database apps using Python, SQLAlchemy and Qt.

Answer (score 0):

hmm, probably more than what you need.

http://dabodev.com/

If you are more interested in lower level stuff, wxPython wiki has a lot of info,  a google reveals

http://wiki.wxpython.org/DataAwareControlsMixin

but this might not be enough for you :)

Comment: iondiode, thank you, i'll take a look at your recommendations.